# Updating a record when it's not exist in the master data

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hello everyone i'm very much stuck at this point...
I already tried and tried and tried but still got no results, and the problems got more complex
I wanted to make a "dimension" type of thing..

So i wanted to make things like this, but always :

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
```

and then SATISH MARKS GOT HIGHER

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 2021/04/11| 0
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
1  |SATISH| 100   | 11/04/2021 | 9999/12/31| 0
```

Then in the date 2021/04/12 SATISH records from STUDENT TABLE not exist (physically deleted). it will become like this

```
ID | NAME | MARKS | START_DATE | END_DATE  | DELETE_FLAG
1  |SATISH| 90    | 2021/03/31 | 2021/04/11| 1
2  |KUMAR | 100   | 2021/03/31 | 9999/12/31| 0
1  |SATISH| 100   | 11/04/2021 | 2021/04/12| 1
```

I've already tried with the insert/update and update step , but still stuck...
Maybe someone know ? Pretty please... :(

This is the transformation i've been trying to

[link transformation](https://filebin.net/l1p7pymmgut3erd8)

Comment: See the below link if that helps.                           https://www.allabouttechnologies.co.in/etl/merge-rowsdiff-in-pentaho/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look my solution from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e8PGpp0rzm3ZHC9DCXanX25snQIf942O?usp=sharing). Frankly your provided transformation should work also i think. Anyways, in my transformation -

1. I consider unique row with combination of (ID+NAME+MARKS)
2. Filter deleted row and update Dimention table
3. Filter new row and insert into Dimention table

[image]

Comment: Hello sakil, thankyou somuch for replying, but i wanted to ask , in the master i had ahmmed with 77 marks, in the dim i had ahmmed with 99 marks, why it didn't says "changed" instead it says the 77 is new, the 99 is deleted?

Comment: In the step "Merge rows (diff)" ,  please remove 'marks' from the "key field section". And ADD 'marks' in the "Value to Comapre" Section. Then you will found the change option.

Comment: is there a way i can bought you a cup of coffee?

Comment: :)   If you found your answer then you can accept this. So that other Pentaho users gets help with this answer.